# Update a column in the database, from a list

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update a column in the database, from a list

```
command = new SqlCommand("update Login_Users set Password=@a  where UserName !='" + null + "'", Db);
Db.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = Encrypt(list[i]);         
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",list[i]);                    
    int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but I get this error:

> variable name already been declared

Answer (score 1):

Your command only has one parameter, but you are attempting to *add* a new one through each loop (via `AddWithValue` ... *add* with value).

Either put the `command` declaration in the loop (as below), or use one of the other methods to update the value.

```
Db.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   command = new SqlCommand("update Login_Users set Password=@a  where UserName !='" + null + "'", Db);
   list[i] = Encrypt(list[i]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",list[i]);
   int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül would that not be an alternative?  If you create a new `command` each iteration, there would be no need to clear?

Comment: Not with the `command = new SqlCommand...` it will be a new command object with an empty `Parameters` collection.

Comment: can you help me with an example, because i tried to add an array instead of =@a, but it didnt work.

Comment: So you're trying to pass in multiple possible passwords?  In fact, looking at your code, it's not clear what you are trying to do - the sql says reset **all** passwords, why would you ever need to apply a loop to that command?  Only the last one would have any effect.  I recommend asking a new question and link to it in the comments of this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. In query you have one parameter called @a - check if your list has only one item. If not that's problem. Meybe it will be better to remove for loop and assign all parameters manually.
2. Why in query you do something like this:

   > where UserName !='" + null + "'"

   I think much more readable is like this:

   > where UserName !=''

   or

   > where UserName <>''

Answer (score 0):

You have setup your SqlCommand with a SQL statement that includes a parameter `@a`. With that set, you can call the command multiple times via the `ExecuteQuery` after setting the parameter `@a` to different values.

Within your `for` loop, the statement `command.Parameters.AddWithValue()` is potentially adding to the command additional parameter, but no two parameters can have the same value so if your loop is executed more than once, you'll get the error you received.

Your SQL statement appears to be setting the password of all records in **Login_Users** to some encrypted value multiple times based on your list. If I understand correctly, maybe this would do what you want:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("update Login_Users set Password=@a  where UserName !='" + null + "'", Db);
Db.Open();
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@a",null));

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@a"].Value = Encrypt(list[i]);
    int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Good luck!